# amCharts 4 pie chart - How to combine smaller slices into one? groupPercent missing in v4

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm testing amCharts 4. In amcharts 3 there was a groupPercent property to combine smaller slices in a piechart.

```
"groupPercent": 1.1,
```

https://www.amcharts.com/dataviz-tip-18-combine-smaller-pie-chart-slices/

What's the equivalent for amcharts 4 ?

https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/pieseries/

```
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.PieSeries());
```

Comment: There currently isn't equivalent functionality in v4. I opened a ticket requesting this functionality. You can follow its progress [here](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/509).